# Removing whitespaces using regex python

Tags: python, list, loops, replace

I am trying to amend each line of a file to remove any parts beginning with the character **'('** or containing a number/character in square brackets **i.e.'[2]**':

```
f = open('/Users/name/Desktop/university_towns.txt',"r")
listed = []
import re 
for i in f.readlines():
    if i.find(r'\(.*?\)\n'): 
       here = re.sub(r'\(.*?\)\[.*?\]\n', "", i)
       listed.append(here)
    elif i.find(r' \(.*?\)\n'):
       here = re.sub(r' \(.*?\)\[.*?\]\n', "", i)
       listed.append(here)
    elif i.find(r' \[.*?\]\n'): 
       here = re.sub(r' \[.*?\]\n', "", i)
       listed.append(here) 
    else:
       here = re.sub(r'\[.*?\]\n', "", i)
       listed.append(here)
```

A **sample** of my **input** data:

```
Platteville (University of Wisconsin–Platteville)[2]
River Falls (University of Wisconsin–River Falls)[2]
Stevens Point (University of Wisconsin–Stevens Point)[2]
Waukesha (Carroll University)
Whitewater (University of Wisconsin–Whitewater)[2]
Wyoming[edit]
Laramie (University of Wyoming)[5]
```

A sample of my output data:

```
Platteville 
River Falls 
Stevens Point 
Waukesha (Carroll University)
Whitewater 
Wyoming[edit]
Laramie
```

However, I do not want the parts such as '(Carroll University)' or '[edit]'.

How can I **amend my formula**?

I would be so grateful if anyone could give me any advice!

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/I6ZJhq/1

Comment: Why is `pandas` tagged here? Don't see much relevance with respect to the question.

Comment: @MayankPorwal sorry to upset you! It's been removed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
import re 

with open(ur_file) as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        if m:=re.search(r'^([^([]+)', line):  # Python 3.8+
            print(m.group(1))
```

If your Python is prior to 3.8 without the [Walrus](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/):

```
with open(ur_file) as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        m=re.search(r'^([^([]+)', line)
        if m:
            print(m.group(1))
```

Prints:

```
Platteville 
River Falls 
Stevens Point 
Waukesha 
Whitewater 
Wyoming
Laramie
```

The regex explained:

```
^([^([]+)

^                            start of the line
 ^       ^                   capture group
   ^   ^                     character class
     ^                       class of characters OTHER THAN ( and [
        ^                    + means one or more
```

[Here is the regex on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/EPidpz/1/)

Comment: could you explain in a bit more detail what this means: r'^([^(\[]+)'

Comment: so effectively it's saying one or more of any characters within () or [] that are not "()" or "[]"

Comment: The `[]` defines a character class of the characters inside. If you add `[^]` negates what is inside. So `[^(]` is a SINGLE character OTHER THAN `(`. Now add a repletion operator and you get a string of characters other than the characters inside the negated character class. So `[^([]+` is all the character up to a `(` or a `[`.

Comment: If I store m.group(1) as a variable, here = print(m.group(1)) and then print(here) returns a None at the bottom of the list. How can I remove this?

Comment: `here = print(m.group(1))` is not storing `m.group(1)`. It is storing the result of `print` which is `None`

Comment: yes I have changed it to listed = [], here = m.group(1), then listed.append(here)

Comment: It is too complicated to try in debug in comments. `listed = [], here = m.group(1)` is a `ValueError` if you have it just like that...

Answer (score 0):

Use this RegEx instead:

`\(.*\)|\[.*\]`

Like so:

`re.sub(r'\(.*\)|\[.*\]', '', i)`

This will substitute anything in parenthesis (`\(.*\)`) or (`|`) anything in square brackets (`\[.*\]`)

Answer (score 0):

If after a vectorised solution which is much faster and more readable than a loop. Then try;

Data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'text':['Platteville (University of Wisconsin–Platteville)[2]','River Falls (University of Wisconsin–River Falls)[2]','Stevens Point (University of Wisconsin–Stevens Point)[2]','Waukesha (Carroll University)','Whitewater (University of Wisconsin–Whitewater)[2]','Wyoming[edit]','Wyoming[edit]']})
```

Regex extract

```
df['name']=df.text.str.extract('([A-Za-z\s+]+(?=\(|\[))')
```

Regex Breakdown

Capture any `[A-Za-z\s+]` UpperCase, Lowercase letters that are followed by space

`(?=\(|\[))` and that are immediately followed by special character(` or special character [

[image]

Comment: thanks so much! How can I do this for each line an opened text file (rather than a dataframe)?

Comment: If thats the case, a for loop should be ok

Comment: you see the second plus sign in this formula '([A-Za-z\s+]+(?=\(|\[))', am I correct in saying that this means one or more occurences of '[A-Za-z\s+]'? In other words, what is the need for this second plus sign?

Comment: i'd argue that string methods in Pandas are not faster than in vanilla python. numbers yes, but strings i think python is faster.